# Angular UI-Router: Adding Custom Events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement a reliable way of checking whether a user is going forward or back down the history stack, that will work within both the angular context, and outside it via the browser back / forward buttons.

So basically, whether I use `$window.history.back()` inside my service for instance, or the browsers forward / back buttons, I want to know which direction I've navigated.

What I've done is hook up my panel service to Angular ui-router, by adding a custom configuration object named `panel` to each state that I want to have open inside a panel. ***(as below)***

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
        url: '/ah',
        abstract: true
    })

    .state('app.test', {
        url: '/test',
        panel: {
            template: '<h1>Test</h1><br /><br /><button data-ng-click="clickMe()">Click Me</button>',
            controller: 'testController'
        }
    });

}]);
```

I am currently using ui-router's `$stateChangeStart` event to capture said object, and appropriately open a panel if said object is present. ***(as below)***

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'PanelService', function ($rootScope, $state, PanelService) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        if (toState.hasOwnProperty('panel')) {

            PanelService.open({
                templateUrl: toState.panel.templateUrl,
                template: toState.panel.template,
                controller: toState.panel.controller,
                title: toState.panel.title,
                scope: event.targetScope,
                resolve: toState.panel.resolve
            });

        }

    });

}]);
```

But I am running into a problem as I mentioned above, where I cannot reliably discern whether or not I am forward or back down the history stack, so that I know when to open or close a panel.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfm8g42h/3/) of it in action.

I've tried coming up with a more elegant solution, but I am struggling to figure out what the best way would be to approach this. My thoughts are to possibly extend / decorate ui-router to add events such as `$onHistoryBack` or `$onHistoryForward` perhaps? But I have yet to find a way to do this.

Your advice and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question! Perhaps something like [angular-history](https://github.com/decipherinc/angular-history) could be to your advantage in this case? Or borrow some ideas if you're not wanting an addition dependency perhaps

Comment: Thanks @scniro. I have actually looked at that, and I am not entirely sure how it would benefit my situation, could you possibly elaborate a little bit on what you've got in mind? Also, `angular-history` seems to be a supercharged wrapper for angular's `$watch`, would that be a fair assessment?